# MySQLi - When you have a query with more than 15 '?', and sisisissssisisiss, how do you keep track?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

When MySQLi statements are small, they are super easy to use. However, once you have more than a certain amount of bounded parameters, it gets extremely hard to track the `s` and `i` are synced up property. Like the following example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO transaction_table (eventide, proxid, valid, fname, lame, email, studentid, status, affiliation, grade, error_statement, gender, netid, residence, school, department, major1, major2, dob, type, level) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
    $grade_new = gradeChanger($grade);
    $stmt->bind_param('iiisssiisssssissssiss',$_POST['pid'],$_POST['proxid'],$valid,$fname,$lname,$email,$studentid,$status,$affiliation,$grade_new,$error_submit,$gender,$netid,$residence,$school,$department,$major1,$major2,$dob,$type,$level);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Is there an easier way to separate the `i` and `s`? like this, I feel like if you would be able to break up the `bind_param` in groups, like so, it would be way easier to read. Is there anyway to do anything like this?

```
$stmt->bind_param('iiis', $_POST['pid'], $_POST['proxid'], $valid, $fname);
$stmt->bind_param('ssii', $lname, $email, $studentid, $status);
$stmt->bind_param('sass', $affiliation, $grade_new, $error_submit, $gender);
$stmt->bind_param('siss', $netid, $residence, $school, $department);
$stmt->bind_param('ssiss', $major1, $major2, $dob, $type, $level);
```

Is the only solution to switch to `PDO`?

Comment: you could use named parameters instead. Then you're not stuck having to manually count `?` positions and trying to remember if you're binding parameter #16 or #17. the named parameters can be specified in ANY order. But it would require many more ->bind()-type calls

Comment: What's stopping you from writing a helper method (or class) that accepts an array of values and types and calls `bind_param` with the appropriate arguments? You could also seamlessly integrate this code by extending from the mysqli classes appropriately.

Comment: That's because it isn't PDO ;-) @MaximeLorant

Comment: @MarcB, mysqli doesn't support named parameters.

Comment: To be honest, I've never been able to figure out why mysqli (or any other DB extension) needs to be told the data type at all. Save for very specific situations (the `LIMIT` clause won't cast strings to int) it doesn't seem to serve any obvious purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is to dynamically call the `bind_param` method.  You obviously know whether to use `i` or `s` with each variable, so let's put all of that into an array (in the correct order).

```
$params = array(
    array('i', $_POST['pid']),
    array('i', $_POST['proxid']),
    array('i', $valid),
    array('s', $fname),
    // etc.
);
```

Then you can loop over this to build the "format string" to pass to `bind_param`.

```
$bind_params = array('');
foreach($params as &$vals){
    $bind_params[0] .= $vals[0];
    $bind_params[] =& $vals[1];
}
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bind_params);
```

This should make it easier for you to add/remove values and to keep track of them.

Comment: I've often asked myself the same question as the OP asked, wondering if there was a simple or simpler solution than what the OP is using; and this looks very promising. I'll have to test it soon. One would kind of wonder if there was a way to simply add an extra parameter to a POST variable. For example (and a very crude example I might add) `$_POST['pid']['i']` - `$_POST['fname']['s']` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I just kinda made this up! :-D  It seems slightly simpler than other solutions.  Your `$_POST` suggestion could work too.  This is just a crude example, feel to expand it however you wish :-)

Comment: Ah, but you're by far much more experienced than I ;-) However, had I stuck with programming in Turbo Pascal (many moons ago) and not made a right turn towards graphic arts, I'd of probably been able to code it. Turbo Pascal and PHP look so much alike. I've only gotten back into programming for just under a year now, and what with having to learn DB stuff on top of that, makes in having a lot on my plate ;-) lol

Comment: Hey Rocket, have a look at what just popped up as an answer to another question, just a few minutes ago. Kind of what I had in mind earlier >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/21318726/

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Ah!  I understand.  Yeah, that could work too.  :-)

Comment: With a bit sanding and polishing up the edges, it could very well work ;-) I'm going to try and come up with something on my side, hopefully it will make my life a little simpler at the same time.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Glad my random ideas can help people :-D

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using named parameters, like `:pid`, `:proxy`, etc.  I know that `PDOStatment::bindParam` supports this.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Only PDO supports this, not MySQLi (which he is using).

Answer (score 1):

yes, At this point, its better to use PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is Object Oriented too.

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES (:name,:age)");
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name1, ':age' => $age1));
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name2, ':age' => $age2));
```