# Separate two values in a POST

Tags: php, post

I have two different values in a POST,

I want to separate 25 and 99 in PHP.

It will be always separate by |.

```
 $_POST['MYPOST'] = 25|99;
```

Thanks.

Comment: they should be in separate post fields to start with

Answer (score 7):

Use [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with [`list()`](http://www.php.net/list)

```
list($value1, $value2) = explode('|', $_POST['MYPOST']);
echo $value1; // 25
echo $value2; // 99
```

Comment: Thanks i believed it will be harder !